# Can't see SVG text

Tags: svg

I lack a basic understanding of `<svg>` and `<text>` within.

I would expect to see 39 svg sub-elements, 100px tall, with legible text in each.

http://jsfiddle.net/pn5sj8ge/

Comment: You have svg elements inside your svg element... I don't think you're meant to do that

Comment: I meant to throw away this question but it got posted anyways.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this is happening is mainly because you are using nested `<svg>` elements.

When you don't specify an `x` and `y` in your `<text>` elements, they default to (0,0).  This means that the bottom-left of your text is at the top-left of each `<svg>` element.  Nested/child `<svg>` elements default to `overflow: hidden`, so each text element is off the top of each SVG.  All you are seeing is a few pixels where the glyphs drop below the baseline.

You can verify this by setting `overflow="visible"` or `style="overflow: visible"` on your child `<svg>` elements.  The text will become visible again.  Well all except the first one because it is off the top of the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/pn5sj8ge/5/

Unless you have a special reason for using nested `<svg>` elements, there is no need for it.  Just use `<text>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The text at 0, 0 and above the elements. Just give the text elements a `y` attribute:

```
<svg width="100%" height="3900px">
    <svg y="0" height="100px" width="100%">
        <text y="50">calories</text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pn5sj8ge/4/